# What mechanism causes a View.onSaveInstanceState to be called in Fragment to Fragment navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-lifecycle

There is a lot of noise surrounding this subject on SO and Google, so bear with me.

When performing **Fragment to Fragment** navigation, you see this lifecycle:

```
Fragment1: onPause
Fragment1: onStop
Fragment1: onDestroyView

Fragment2: onCreateView
Fragment2: onStart
Fragment2: onResume
```

(You can see this in this picture stolen from [here](https://bricolsoftconsulting.com/state-preservation-in-backstack-fragments/))
[image]

There is no call to a `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState` as the Fragment instance is still alive - only it's view has been destroyed.

*What mechanism therefore is saving the View's state and restoring it, and how?*

Comment: Have you tried rotating the screen ? ie. portrait to landscape and so on.

Answer (score -1):

onSaveInstanceState will be called according to documentation:

> This method will occur after onStop() for applications
>   targeting platforms starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.P. For
>   applications targeting earlier platform versions this method will
>   occur before onStop() and there are no guarantees about whether it
>   will occur before or after onPause().

In onSaveInstanceState you can put all the data you want to persist in the bundle

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
// put data you want to persist to outState
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
```

}

And then in `onCreate` you can check if you need to restore your persisted data:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
  // activity created for the first time
} else {
  // activity re-created, restore data from savedInstanceState
}
```

}

You can also read more about it here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Fragment to Fragment navigation doesn't involved onSaveInstanceState() - There is a lot of noise around this topic because of the assumption it uses the same mechanism as Activity to Activity (or configuration change)

Comment: I've updated the question to highlight the situation I'm asking about

Comment: If you want to persist Fragment's data, while navigating, you should use `ViewModel`. It is always created in association with a scope (a fragment or an activity) and will be retained as long as the scope is alive. E.g. if it is a `Fragment`, until its `onDestroy` was called and there was **NO configuration change** (device rotation). If you want to persist data across multiple Fragments, have a common activity scoped ViewModel and observe it's `LiveData` in those Fragments, who need it. Let me know, if this is what you want, I can update my answer with some code examples. –